# How to efficiently insert 10,000 rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to load roughly 10,000 entries into a SQL Server table, and have found it doesn't allow loading over 1,000 row values. The error is shown below:

> The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

Currently I'm trying to run a simple SQL script inside Data Studio.

```
INSERT INTO [<table>] (<COLUMNS>)
VALUES (<rows>)
```

I was wondering if there was any way to bypass this error within SQL Server, or if I need a separate script which then loads the data onto the server.

Comment: It depends how you are inserting the records. Are you using a utility, SQL Script, EntityFramework, ADO.NET? A bit more context of what you are trying to achieve will help people answer the question.

Comment: 1000s of rows is very little data if you use the proper bulk import tools, like BULK INSERT or `bcp`. In a .NET client application you can use SqlBulkCopy. This will allow you to load millions of rows in a stream

Comment: @marc_s You actually don't need to split the `INSERT` statement, you can use the following form with more than 1000 rows: `INSERT .... SELECT ... FROM (VALUES (....), (...), .....) AS v(.....)`. But you are asking two different questions: how to get around this restriction, and how to do this fast (probably with `BULK INSERT` or bcp or SqlBulkCopy instead)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL speed up performance of insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090243/sql-speed-up-performance-of-insert)

Answer (score 0):

maybe so?

```
    CREATE TABLE #Bokning(
        [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PersonNr] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,
        [RegNr] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
        [Datum] [date] NOT NULL,
        [PassTyp] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
        [PassNr] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PassInfo] [varchar](50) NULL
    )

    DECLARE @Content NVARCHAR(MAX);

    -- Load the content from the file
    SELECT @Content = BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\Bokningar.SQL', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents;

    WITH Raw_CTE AS (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS LineNumber,
            TRIM(value) AS SplitLine
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Content, CHAR(10))
    )
    ,
    NumberedLines_CTE AS (
        SELECT
            SUBSTRING(SplitLine, 2, LEN(SplitLine) - 4) AS SplitLine
        FROM Raw_CTE
        WHERE LEN(SplitLine) > 10
    ),
    SplitLinesCTE AS (
        SELECT
            REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(value)), '''', '') AS ColumnValue,
            FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) / 7) AS RowNum,
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) % 7 AS ColNum
        FROM NumberedLines_CTE
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SplitLine, ',')
    )
INSERT INTO #Bokning 
SELECT
    [0] AS ID,
    [1] AS PersonNr,
    [2] AS RegNr,
    [3] AS Datum,
    [4] AS PassTyp,
    [5] AS PassNr,
    [6] AS PassInfo
FROM SplitLinesCTE
PIVOT (
    MAX(ColumnValue) FOR ColNum IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) AS PivotTable;
SELECT * FROM #Bokning
```

Code is using CTEs instead TEMP TABLE and PIVOT for splitting CSV as a way to code it in MS SQL Server since 2005. The code is self-explanatory - rows from the file are read into a table with the source line number and raw data. This will be split and flipped to columns matching the target table layout and inserted as the last step. This approach is a workaround for the limitation on the number of lines in one SQL INSERT by MS.

Comment: Why did you think adding a solution using CTEs and PIVOT was a good example of bulk inserts? You should explain your logic instead of posting code only.

Comment: I am using CTEs and PIVOT as a way to code SQL in MS SQL Server since 2005. The code is self-explanatory - rows from the file are read into a table with the source line number and raw data. This will be split and flipped to columns matching the target table layout and inserted as the last step. This approach is a workaround for the limitation on the number of lines in one SQL INSERT by MS.

Comment: It will certainly work around the issue... but why not just use [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) especially if the data is already in a file... Your answer is not very clear at all, without an example of the file how is someone even supposed to replicate your solution. This was a poor question to start with because it needs more focus but your answer doesn't make it any better.

Comment: 1) Data to be inserted comes in the file as an INSERT statement and not as CSV.

2) File is not compatible with MS SQL CSV, some columns need to be removed or manipulated or added.

3) ROW_NUMBER() -- can be used to skip the first two lines - INSERT and VALUES 

4) some calculated or joined data for referential integrity. 

5) new IDENTITY numbers can be added as PK into existing series in the target table, instead of the original. For example, to merge two or more source tables in a new design.

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback but the intent on this site is that you take the feedback and improve the post, then in reply I am likely to remove my comment. It is about creating content for the wider community. ;) because you are using `OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\Bokningar.SQL', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents` it is implied that the data is in a standard data schema format and not SQL insert statements, so to explain you should atleast include an example of the file. The OP was very vague, so we shouldn't have answered until they provided better focus

Comment: So the burden is now on you to provide that focus and provide us with a reproducible _answer_ which should include an example of the input file that would make your solution actually work. I understand now what you are trying to do, but I think your response still needs heavy edits to make this consumable to those who might need it.