# Copy mysql database from remote server to local computer

Tags: mysql

I'm under VPN and I don't have SSH access to remote server.

I can connect to remote database by console

```
mysql -u username -p -h remote.site.com
```

Now I'm trying to clone the remote database to local computer

```
mysqldump -u username -p -h remote.site.com mysqldump | mysql -u root -ppassword webstuff
```

And I've got error

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'webstaff'@'10.75.1.2' 
(using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

How to copy mysql database from remote server to local computer?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Assuming the following command works successfully:

```
mysql -u username -p -h remote.site.com
```

The syntax for `mysqldump` is identical, and outputs the database dump to `stdout`. Redirect the output to a local file on the computer:

```
mysqldump -u username -p -h remote.site.com DBNAME > backup.sql
```

Replace `DBNAME` with the name of the database you'd like to download to your computer.

Comment: I've got error "mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'webstuff'@'%' to database 'webstuff' when using LOCK TABLES". It seems that I don't have permission to do administrative task

Comment: That's correct, looks like you'll have to grant yourself additional privileges, if possible. :)

Comment: I can't get additional privileges, I'll try another possibility

Comment: @megas: instead of granting privileges, you may pass the --single-transaction option to mysqldump.  For example: `mysqldump --single-transaction -u username -p -h remote.site.com DBNAME > backup.sql`

Comment: Additionally, I was looking for a way to backup all databases at once, for which I found a solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497869/export-and-import-all-mysql-databases-at-one-time

Comment: I've also got an error while running command
"mysqldump -u <username> -p -h <IP address> <DBName> > dbBackup.sql"
mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<IP Address>' (110) when trying to connect

Comment: @JulianH.Lam is it possible to get the dump in `csv` format?

Answer (score 25):

Check syntax and execute one command at a time, then verify output.

```
mysqldump -u remoteusername -p remotepassword -h your.site.com databasename > dump.sql

mysql -u localusername -p localpassword databasename < dump.sql
```

Once you've matched all passwords, you can use pipe.

Comment: There shouldn't space between -p and password for ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Often our databases are really big and the take time to take dump directly from remote machine to other machine as our friends other have suggested above.

In such cases what you can do is to take the dump on remote machine using [MYSQLDUMP Command](http://www.oyewiki.com/mysql/mysql-dump-how-to-take-mysql-dump-export-mysql-data)

**MYSQLDUMP -uuser -p --all-databases > file_name.sql**

and than transfer that file from remote server to your machine using [Linux SCP Command](http://www.oyewiki.com/linux/linux-unix-scp-command)

**scp user@remote_ip:~/mysql_dump_file_name.sql ./**

Answer (score 2):

This can have different reasons like:

- You are using an incorrect password
- The MySQL server got an error when trying to resolve the IP address of the client host to a name
- No privileges are granted to the user

You can try one of the following steps:

To reset the password for the remote user by:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR some_user@ip_addr_of_remote_client=PASSWORD('some_password');
```

To grant access to the user by:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, LOCK TABLES ON YourDB.* TO user@Host IDENTIFIED by 'password';
```

Hope this helps you, if not then you will have to go through the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html)

Comment: Another possibility being that the user (root or webstaff?) is not allowed access from that client address, maybe root is restricted to localhost/127.0.0.1

Comment: In that case, then the original `mysql` command wouldn't work either, but @megas says it does work.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this gist.

https://gist.github.com/ecdundar/789660d830d6d40b6c90

```
#!/bin/bash

# copymysql.sh

# GENERATED WITH USING ARTUR BODERA S SCRIPT
# Source script at: https://gist.github.com/2215200

MYSQLDUMP="/usr/bin/mysqldump"
MYSQL="/usr/bin/mysql"

REMOTESERVERIP=""
REMOTESERVERUSER=""
REMOTESERVERPASSWORD=""
REMOTECONNECTIONSTR="-h ${REMOTESERVERIP} -u ${REMOTESERVERUSER} --password=${REMOTESERVERPASSWORD} "

LOCALSERVERIP=""
LOCALSERVERUSER=""
LOCALSERVERPASSWORD=""
LOCALCONNECTION="-h ${LOCALSERVERIP} -u ${LOCALSERVERUSER} --password=${LOCALSERVERPASSWORD} "

IGNOREVIEWS=""
MYVIEWS=""
IGNOREDATABASES="select schema_name from information_schema.SCHEMATA where schema_name != 'information_schema' and schema_name != 'mysql' and schema_name != 'performance_schema'  ;"

# GET A LIST OF DATABASES
databases=`$MYSQL $REMOTECONNECTIONSTR -e "${IGNOREDATABASES}" | tr -d "| " | grep -v schema_name`

# COPY ALL TABLES
for db in $databases; do
    # GET LIST OF ITEMS
    views=`$MYSQL $REMOTECONNECTIONSTR --batch -N -e "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type='VIEW' and table_schema='$db';"
    IGNOREVIEWS=""
    for view in $views; do
        IGNOREVIEWS=${IGNOREVIEWS}" --ignore-table=$db.$view " 
    done
    echo "TABLES "$db
    $MYSQL $LOCALCONNECTION --batch -N -e "create database $db; "
    $MYSQLDUMP $REMOTECONNECTIONSTR $IGNOREVIEWS --compress --quick --extended-insert  --skip-add-locks --skip-comments --skip-disable-keys --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-triggers --single-transaction  $db | mysql $LOCALCONNECTION  $db 
done

# COPY ALL PROCEDURES
for db in $databases; do
    echo "PROCEDURES "$db
    #PROCEDURES
    $MYSQLDUMP $REMOTECONNECTIONSTR --compress --quick --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt --skip-triggers $db | \
    sed -r 's/DEFINER=`[^`]+`@`[^`]+`/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER/g' | mysql $LOCALCONNECTION  $db 
done

# COPY ALL TRIGGERS
for db in $databases; do
    echo "TRIGGERS "$db
    #TRIGGERS
    $MYSQLDUMP $REMOTECONNECTIONSTR  --compress --quick --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt --triggers $db | \
    sed -r 's/DEFINER=`[^`]+`@`[^`]+`/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER/g' | mysql $LOCALCONNECTION  $db 
done

# COPY ALL VIEWS
for db in $databases; do
    # GET LIST OF ITEMS
    views=`$MYSQL $REMOTECONNECTIONSTR --batch -N -e "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type='VIEW' and table_schema='$db';"`
    MYVIEWS=""
    for view in $views; do
        MYVIEWS=${MYVIEWS}" "$view" " 
    done
    echo "VIEWS "$db    
    if [ -n "$MYVIEWS" ]; then
      #VIEWS
      $MYSQLDUMP $REMOTECONNECTIONSTR --compress --quick -Q -f --no-data --skip-comments --skip-triggers --skip-opt --no-create-db --complete-insert --add-drop-table $db $MYVIEWS | \
      sed -r 's/DEFINER=`[^`]+`@`[^`]+`/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER/g'  | mysql $LOCALCONNECTION  $db  
    fi    
done

echo   "OK!"
```

Answer (score 2):

> Copy mysql database from remote server to local computer

I ran into the same problem. And I could not get it done with the other answers. So here is how I finally did it (yes, a beginner tutorial):

Step 1: Create a new database in your local phpmyadmin.

Step 2: Dump the database on the remote server into a sql file (here I used Putty/SSH):

```
mysqldump --host="mysql5.domain.com" --user="db231231" --password="DBPASSWORD" databasename > dbdump.sql
```

Step 3: Download the `dbdump.sql` file via FTP client (should be located in the root folder)

Step 4: Move the sql file to the folder of your localhost installation, where `mysql.exe` is located. I am using uniform-server, this would be at `C:\uniserver\core\mysql\bin\`, with XAMPP it would be `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`

Step 5: Execute the `mysql.exe` as follows:

```
 mysql.exe -u root -pYOURPASSWORD YOURLOCALDBNAME < dbdump.sql
```

Step 6: Wait... depending on the file size. You can check the progress in phpmyadmin, seeing newly created tables.

Step 7: Done. Go to your local phpmyadmin to check if the database has been filled with the entire data.

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Note 1: When starting the uniformer-server you can specify a password for mysql. This is the one you have to use above for YOURPASSWORD.

Note 2: If the login does not work and you run into password problems, check your password if it contains special characters like `!`. If so, then you probably need to escape them `\!`.

Note 3: In case not all mysql data can be found in the local db after the import, it could be that there is a problem with the mysql directives of your dbdump.sql

Answer (score 1):

Better yet use a oneliner:

Dump remoteDB to localDB:

```
mysqldump -uroot -pMypsw -h remoteHost remoteDB | mysql -u root -pMypsw localDB
```

Dump localDB to remoteDB:

```
mysqldump -uroot -pmyPsw localDB | mysql -uroot -pMypsw -h remoteHost remoteDB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\>mysqldump -u root -p -h ip address --databases database_name -r sql_file.sql
Enter password: your_password
```

Comment: change ip address with another system ip from where you want to take backup.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not remote server but local server. The logic should be the same. To copy and backup my local machine MAMP database to my local desktop machine folder, go to console then

```
mysqldump -h YourHostName -u YourUserNameHere -p YourDataBaseNameHere > DestinationPath/xxxwhatever.sql
```

In my case `YourHostName` was `localhost`. `DestinationPath` is the path to the download; you can drag and drop your desired destination folder and it will paste the path in.

Then password may be asked:

```
Enter password: xxxxxxxx
```