# How to remote pulling mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh

i was looking this: [Copy mysql database from remote server to local computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435144/copy-mysql-database-from-remote-server-to-local-computer)

And it's the same case as me! but what i need use to connect with the following code:

```
mysql -u username -p -h remote.site.com
```

What is this "console"?

Thanks!

EDIT: If there's not possible to pull db by this method, exists some php script that you put db name, server and password and they pull automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have mysql utilities on your machine.

Go to your start menu on your PC and click on "run"

Then when the dos command line come up type in your command.

`mysql -u username -p -h your domain.com`

If you get an error something like "command not recognized" you will have to first navigate to the mysql bin folder 
For example 
`cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin`

Then execute the mysql..... Command.

Note, the remote server has to accept the connection. If you get a connection rejects you may want to make sure your remote server allow such a connection.

Answer (score 0):

"console" has different names which often mean the same thing:

- Terminal window
- DOS prompt
- Command prompt
- Command line

It's the program on your computer which allows to run commands by typing text instead of clicking on icons and buttons.