# Table already exists error when trying to import sql file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to upload a backup sql file through phpMyAdmin.

create the empty db with the same db name as in my import file in phpMyAdmin then use the import function selected from within this empty db.

I get the following error message.

```
#1050 - Table '`db`.`t`' already exists
```

Inside the import file each `CREATE TABLE` statement is suffixed by `IF NOT EXISTS`, so why is this being reported as an error?

```
    --
-- Database: `mbfour`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cars`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars` (
  `car_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `capacity` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cars`
--

INSERT INTO `cars` (`car_id`, `type`, `status`, `capacity`) VALUES
(1, 'automatic', 'built', '4L'),
(2, 'automatic', 'in-production', '2L'),
(3, 'automatic', 'built', '2L'),
(4, 'automatic', 'in-production', '4L');
....
....
```

Is There Any Magic Happens???

After Trying Two Times Then I Import like same Way, It works

Thanks Folks.....

Comment: show your sql script

Comment: I'll bet the `CREATE TABLE` line for `db.t` is missing the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause.

Comment: the import may be using something like this ... use db_x then your import will go to another database

Comment: Ok post the real error instead of `#1050 - Table '\`db\`.\`t\`' already exists` because table name not matched with error.

Comment: In my situation, it was not enough permissions for mysql process for database files. `chmod -R 775` has solved the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please add this at the top of every query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cars`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars`
```

Comment: But this Way U will end up losing the data... The point is just to update the structure leaving the data unattachable.

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cars`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars`;

Please make sure put the semi colon in the 2nd line.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to comment the query of create database in your sql file

Please put comment or remove code in your sql file then try

```
   /* CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars` (
  `car_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `capacity` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue and could not figure it out. When I tried to link the foreign keys to my join table, the query would fail with that same 1050 error message and it would only keep the first relationship I had created.

I noticed that phpmyadmin automatically gave the constraint it kept a name, I simply copied that name (under "Constrain name") and replaced the "1" with a "2" and ran the query again, no problem. Both relationships were saved.

Hope this helps.