# How to make dump of all MySQL databases besides two

Tags: mysql

this is probably massively simple, however I will be doing this for a live server and don't want to mess it up.

Can someone please let me know how I can do a mysqldump of all databases, procedures, triggers etc except the mysql and performance_schema databases?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497869/export-and-import-all-mysql-databases-at-one-time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can dump several schemas at the same time :

```
mysqldump --user=[USER] --password=[PASS] --host=[HOST] --databases mydb1 mydb2 mydb3 [...] --routines > dumpfile.sql
```

OR

```
mysqldump --user=[USER] --password=[p --host=[HOST] --all-databases --routines > dumpfile.sql
```

concerning the last command, if you don't want to dump performance_schema (EDIT: as mentioned by @Barranka, by default mysqldump won't dump it), mysql, phpMyAdmin schema, etc. you just need to ensure that [USER] can't access them.

Comment: I like when answers from different users enrich each other

Comment: exactly ! this is what stackoverflow is made for :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's no option in `mysqldump` that you could use to filter the databases list, but you can run two commands:

```
# DATABASES=$(mysql -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES" | grep -Ev '(mysql|performance_schema)')
# mysqldump -B $DATABASES
```

Comment: You need to add the `-R` flag to include the stored procedures in the dump (I learned that the hard way :S )

Comment: @Barranka You can add a lot more, but the OP seems to be asking about skipping some databases.

Answer (score 2):

[As stated in the reference manual:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases)

> `mysqldump` does not dump the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or `performance_schema` database by default. To dump either of these, name it explicitly on the command line and also use the `--skip-lock-tables` option. You can also name them with the `--databases` option.

So that takes care of your concern about dumping those databases.

Now, to dump *all* databases, I think you should do something like this:

```
mysqldump -h Host -u User -pPassword -A -R > very_big_dump.sql
```

To test it without dumping all data, you can add the `-d` flag to dump only database, table (and routine) definitions with no data.

As mentioned by Basile in his answer, the easiest way to ommit dumping the `mysql` database is to invoke `mysqldump` with a user that does not have access to it. So the punch line is: use or create a user that has access only to the databases you mean to dump.

Comment: as you mentioned INFORMATION_SCHEMA or performance_schema won't be dumped by default, but `mysql` will be.