# how to backup in rds aws?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Quick help here...

I have these 2 mysql instances... We are not going to pay for this service anymore; so they will be gone... How can I obtain a backup file that I can keep for the future?

I do not have much experience with mysql, and all threads talk about mysqldump, which I don't know if its valid for this case. I also see the option to take a snapshot but I want a file I can save (like a .bak).

See screenshot:

[image: amazon web services]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See This [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.BackingUpAndRestoringAmazonRDSInstances.html).

Comment: Hi virendra, I do appreciate your reply but, the article doesn't provide a way of exporting to a single file; and most of the documentation is related to other version... I may be confused here, I thought there was a quick way of backuping this MySQL 5.1.73a instance. We are going to stop that service; and I wanted to keep some ".bak" for the future just in case; is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices:

1. You can replicate your MySQL instances to MySQL servers running outside AWS. This is a bit of a pain, but will result in a running instance. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html
2. You can use the commandline `mysqldump --all-databases` to generate a (probably *very* large)  .sql file from each database server instance. [Export and Import all MySQL databases at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497869/export-and-import-all-mysql-databases-at-one-time)
3. You can use the commandline `mysqldump` to export a database at a time. This is what I would do.
4. You can use a gui MySQL client -- like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) -- in place of the commandline to export your databases one at a time. This might be easier.

You don't need to, and should not, export the `mysql`, `information_schema`, or `performance_schema` databases; these contain system information and will already exist on another server.

In order to connect from outside AWS, you'll have to set the AWS protections appropriately. And you'll have to know the internet address, username, and password (and maybe port) of the MySQL server at AWS.

Then you can download HeidiSQL (if you're on windows) or some appropriate client software, connect to your database instance, and export your databases at your leisure.

Comment: Thanks Ollie Jones, that is a great answer!

Now a few questions come to my mind…

-this is a MySQL 5.1.73a in rds aws, can I connect from my laptop? I would need a mysql client no my laptop, right? do I need to download any special client?

Thanks again!!