# Backup all databases in seperate files from Mysql in windows 7

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

My OS is **Windows 7** and I am using **MySQL 5.5** version as DB for that I am having **SQLyog(8.71)** as GUI.

Now my problem is I want to take back up of all the databases present in **MySQL**. There are more than 100 databases present in my DB.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As first and important, you should have appropriate privilege for backup all the databases.

If you want to try on **command line**, then follow the instructions in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9498058/3229851).

If you want to try with **SQLyog GUI tool**, you can follow the instructions in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTLmtPsAITo).

Comment: Hey @ Steve.NayLinAung thank you very much for your info... Actually the  you-tube link will work only for enterprise or ultimate editions of SQLYog.. if we are using trail version it is not accepting... So  I am giving the link to download enterprise or ultimate versions of sqlyog so that it will be helpful to others  URL: http://www.irdevelopers.com/post/11745/Webyog-SQLyog-Ultimate-12.0.9.0-x86-x64.html

Comment: And my problem got solved thanks guys\

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a complete script but what i should do:

```
mysql "show-databases" > alldb.txt
```

Now you have a file `alldb.txt` with all database names in it

In a `powershell file` or `command file`,

```
foreach databasename in getlines(alldbd.txt) {
    mysqldump databasename > databasename.sql
}
```

Comment: hi could you please be little bit more clear

Comment: You also must exclude some schemas like information_schema etc. and also include switch -R to have all information about the schema