# ExpressJS SequlizeJS backup MySQL database

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Hi I have a ExpressJS RESTapi project. ORM I used is SequlizeJS. I want to get a db backup and store in the local machine. My db is MySQL db. How do I achieve this using ExpressJS? Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export and Import all MySQL databases at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497869/export-and-import-all-mysql-databases-at-one-time)

Comment: Why do you need `ExpressJS` to take your `MySQL` db backup?

Comment: @DavidR I need store backup in some where and email all the backups end of the day.

Comment: @MickaelB. No I want to do it with ExpressJS. Because I want to email it.

Comment: @PathumKalhan Checkout my answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [backup-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/backup-mysql) module and see if it can help you. Basically it is a small utility which does the backup of your mysql from any remote server which is based on express.js

Note: However it doesn't take care the emailing part, which you may have to write on your own.

Hope this helps!