# How to Restore Mysql database to MS Sql Server in Rails 4 on Windows

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4

I created dump file of database in Mysql.Now i want to restore all the data of mysql to Sql Server.In case for mysql its simple by running source dumpfile name,but how may i restore all the table data for Sql Server and also the syntax of dumpfile is different for Sql Server.

How to Restore Mysql database to MS Sql Server in Rails 4 on Windows

Comment: i am getting this error....while i run rails c or rails s in cmd prompt.

Comment: D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/tenant.rb:41:in `rescue in adapter': The adapter `sqlserver_adapter` is not yet supported (RuntimeError)

Comment: there's no problem when i rub rake db:create,only problem is on running rake db:migrate,rails c,rails s command.

Comment: Please elaborate more on how you are doing the migration, what are the gems involved and the contents of your database.yml config file.
You would also want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621682/import-mysql-database-into-a-ms-sql-server

Comment: default: &default
  mode: odbc
  adapter: sqlserver
  dsn: mydsn
  username: abc
  password: ****
  timeout: 0

development:
  <<: *default
  mode: odbc
  adapter: sqlserver
  dsn: mydsn
  database: abc_development
  username: abc
  password: ****
  timeout: 0

test:
  <<: *default
  mode: odbc
  adapter: sqlserver
  dsn: mydsn
  database: hrms_test
  username: abc
  password: ****
  timeout: 0

production:
  <<: *default
  database: abc_production
  username: sa
  password: <%= ENV['ABC_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

Comment: this i smy database.yml file.Copy it to notepad.

Comment: now i am getting this error......D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods

Comment: all is successfull now...i have followed the link which you have given yesterday....but now i am getting above erro while doing rails s or rails c.

Comment: this is my new question link....reply in that.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247094/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-bundlergemrequireerror-while-doing-rails-s-in-w